# Double integrals for area region

Tags: calculus, integration, area

By using the double integrals,find the area of regions enclosed by curve $y=5-x^2$ and line $y=x+3$

Here is the problem, I've done sketching the graph but I dont know how to solve it . Can someone help me. Thanks

Comment: Where do the curves intersect?  What values can $x$ assume?  For a given value of $x$ what values can $y$ assume?  If you answer these questions, you will be able to set up the integral.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy to see that the two intersection points of $y=5-x^2$ and $y=x+3$ are $(-2,1)$ and $(1,4)$.
So the region bounded by the two curves can be defined as
$$E:=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2:3+x\le y\le 5-x^2, x\in[-2,1]\}\implies$$
$$\text{Area}(E)=\int_{-2}^1\int_{3+x}^{5-x^2}dydx=\int_{-2}^1(2-x^2-x)dx=2x-\dfrac{x^3}{3}-\dfrac{x^2}{2}\bigg\vert_{-2}^1$$

Comment: ok thanks !!  Thank you so much. The only thing I dont know is the intersection point but glad that u help me:)